# How queryDSL works with interface?

Tags: java, jdo, querydsl

I have a set of classes that implements the same interface. For example:

```
public interface Employee{
    private String name;

    public void work();
    public String getName();
}

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Accountant implements Employee{
}


@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Secretary implements Employee{
}
```

And another class that holds the Employee implementations:

```
public class Department{
     private ArrayList<Employee> employees;

     public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees();
}
```

I want to get a list of Department that has Employee named "Mary". How should I put my jdo query? Am I missing some annotation to the interface Employee?

I suspect the Q class generated is not correct. I got

```
public final SimplePath<java.util.ArrayList<Employee>>
```

in the generated Q class. Shouldn't it be `ListPath` instead of `SimplePath`?

Comment: Could you also provide the relevant annotations?

Comment: added the annotation to the question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here

- `Employee` is not recognized as an entity type, since it is not annotated
- `ArrayList` is not a supported List type in Querydsl, only Collection interfaces are supported

Consider annotating `Employee` and use `List` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: 1. Employee is an interface that doesn't exist in the database while Accountant and Secretary do exist. What kind of annotation should I put to Employee? 2. That means only the direct subinterfaces are supported?

Comment: For JDO there is no MappedSuperclass, so I don't know. Interfaces are supported, they are just not automatically turned into Q-types, annotations do that.

Comment: So I should put @QueryEntity to Employee?

Comment: It should be @QuerySupertype, but it is currently not supported for the JDOAnnotationProcessor, I created a ticket for it https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/565

Comment: After the new change is deployed, the generated code should be ListPath<QEmployee> if I change it to List<Employee>, am I correct?